# Xcode 4.2 templates for iOS 4 applications

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

Do you guys know if there is a place I can download templates for Xcode 4? As I have to still mantain compatibility with iOS 4 devices, I would like to have some of the Xcode 3 templates available on Xcode 4 (as those for creating apps with navigation control and so on, or the ability to have core data in all of them or not)

Do you guys know where I can find some?

Comment: You don't need to start from a particular template to target iOS 4.x.   The templates don't provide that much for you, and you can easily modify the parts that aren't compatible with iOS 4.x. Starting from a simple view-based template, you can add all the functionality you need pretty easily.

Answer (score 2):

You could install [Xcode 3](http://macfiets.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-download-xcode-3.html), create your project and then open the project file with Xcode 4 instead.

This is what I did with all my old projects, so it's a simple workaround.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Xcode 3 does not run on Lion.

Comment: Hmmm, thats a bummer. Sorry then.